# OrmLite and Common table expressions

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to run a similar query:

```
sql = @"with t(id) as (select 1 )
select * from Project 
where id > (select id from t)";

var projects = this.Db.Query<Project>(sql).ToArray();
```

For some reason the OrmLite decides to treat the sql as as "where" clause, so what ends up running is something like this:

```
select field1, field2 from project where with t(id) .....
```

Does it look for a "select" at a starting position of the query ?
Short of creating a view - is there a way to run query with CTE ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `db.Sql*` API's for raw SQL Queries, e.g:

```
var projects = db.SqlList<Project>(sql);
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks! So Query<> does look into the statement ?

Comment: @Eugene Right [they're for executing raw and untouched SQL](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#new-apis-to-execute-custom-sql)